# Curl of magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Why is the curl of a magnetic field due to a current carrying wire zero everywhere, and infinite in the wire itself?

Answer (score 0):

Its infinite on wire because of infinite current density .

A thin current carrying wire has infinite current density due to wire is considered to have zero volume...

Comment: But why is it zero elsewhere??

Comment: Because there's no $\vec {J}$ or $\frac{d \vec {E}}{dt}$ anywhere else! [See the Maxwell-Ampère Equation].

Comment: Yes according to Maxwell Ampere equation J is zero and therefore curl is also zero. But imagine this , the magnetic field produced due to this wire is circular around the wire i.e. they are curling in the space . So how can their curl be zero? @Philip Wood

Comment: Radially outward fields have curl zero (like electric fields) but why this magnetic field have zero curl?

Comment: Curl is defined locally, not globally; revise the definition! And beware of reading too much into names!

Comment: Ohh.. ok. I didnt think in that way.